# Efficient integral function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, integral

I have a function of the form a*x + b and I want to integrate this function from 0 to t where t will be set to the values of a very large (length 100000) vector repeatedly. I used quad function in a for loop, but it takes too much time to compute the integral for each value in the vector. Is there any efficient way to implement this in Matlab?

Comment: Doesn't this boil down to computing 1/2 * a*t*t + b*t for all elements t of your vector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you dont need to implement it yourself, 
you may search it by using "matlab numerical integration functions"...

First functons comes into my mind are;

```
Trapezoidal --> trapz(X,Y)

Cumulative Trapezoidal --> cumtrapz(X,Y)

Adaptive Lobatto Quadrature --> quadl

Adaptive Gauss-Kronrod Quadrature --> quadgk

Vectorized Quadrature --> quadv
```

Answer (score 0):

cumtrapz();

seriously CumTrapz

It computes the trapazoidal aproximation of the integral.